# best material to absorb Sound

Tags: sound, acoustics

The Loft that I live in used to be a city hall building.
The hallways and lofts have  very high ceilings and have a horrible echo problems.

I am considering hanging some type of sound absorption material either from the ceiling in my loft or on the wall.
Which would be best, the ceiling or the walls, or both?

Comment: without some dimensions it's kinda hard to advise.. maybe you could provide some more insights about the space we're talking about?

Comment: The ceilings are about 16 Ft high and the hallways are 12 ft wide

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how creative you want to get, the most effective sound absorption material I have found so far has been rockwool - which is the material often used for ceiling insulation. You can easily create wooden frames and place rockwool inside these frames as panels, covering them with hessian and stapling the hessian down to the wood, making easily manoeuvrable and placeable panels that will pretty much absorb anything you throw at it.

Rockwool is not particularly expensive and is a very effective way to treat the internals of a room to absorb sound.

Comment: Interesting! Are you not losing the absorbing ability when you cover the surface?

Comment: @Aziraphale As long as the material you cover the rockwool with is sufficiently sparse to allow sound through, no. The rule of thumb in studio room treatment is "if you can put it to your mouth and breath through it, it's fine." So burlap (hessian), grill cloth, cotton, etc are all fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best material to absorb sound will be one of the products sold for this purpose. They usually come as fairly dense boards.

If you can coat all surfaces, yes, you will get better sound absorption, but that can all add up to be fairly expensive.

So the common solution is heavy carpets and drapes, as well as furnishings.